# Filtering Access charts by top 10 sums

Tags: ms-access

I have a chart I've made showing all the customers an outside salesman services proportional to the amount of business each one does. It's a little too cluttered and so I'd like to whittle it down to the top 10 or so customers by sales totals. This needs to be dynamic on a month to month basis as the business can fluctuate a lot.

Here is the SQL for my chart:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(CustPacket_tbl.InvTot) AS SumOfInvTot
SELECT (Format([OrderDate],"mmm"" '""yy")) AS Expr1
FROM CustPacket_tbl
WHERE (((CustPacket_tbl.OutSales)<>"" And (CustPacket_tbl.OutSales)<>"ABC"))
GROUP BY (Year([OrderDate])*12+Month([OrderDate])-1), (Format([OrderDate],"mmm"" '""yy"))
PIVOT CustPacket_tbl.CustName;
```

I've tried adding TOP 10 to the SELECT part of the statement as other links suggest but I don't know SQL well enough yet to fix the syntax errors I'm getting.

Comment: AFAIK, can't do TOP N directly in a CROSSTAB query. Advice I found says to build another query based on the CROSSTAB that has the TOP condition. Or maybe you need to do the TOP in a query then use that query as source for the CROSSTAB.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out on my own, so I might as well share how I did it.

The table in question was created by a make table query pulling from OBDC tables in the company database. (This is done to make the reports run a lot faster) I created two queries that were added into this MTquery, totaling monthly sales by salesman, and by salesman and customer. I then added a field in the MT query that was dividing customer total by complete total, giving the percentage I was after. I lastly used the percentage to filter out customers below a certain threshold until I was satisfied that the results were legible. It works great!